# Mongodb,express find data by _id with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My code is shown below:

```
PostCategory.find({categoryid:category._id.str},function(err,postcategories){
            if(err) return next(err);

            Post.find({_id:postcategories.postid},function(err,posts){
            if(err) return next(err);
                return res.render(__dirname + "/views/categorydetail",  {
                    title: 'İletişim',
                    stylesheet: 'contact'
                });
            }); 
        });
```

I want to find all post which _id is in postcategories.postid. My postcategories returns me list. Here is my postcategories model:

```
module.exports = function(){
    var PostCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        postid:String,
        categoryid:String,
        createddate:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });

    mongoose.model("PostCategory",PostCategorySchema);
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Mongoose model needs to be something like that:

```
var PostCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postid: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
  categoryid: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  createddate:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

mongoose.model("PostCategory", PostCategorySchema);
```

The ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in our case the Post model (same thing for `categoryid` field).

After that, your request becomes really simple:

```
var query = PostCategory.find({ categoryid: category._id });
query.populate('postid');
query.exec(function (err, postcategories) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  // res.render('......');
});
```

For more information, you should read the [Mongoose Query Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) documentation.

EDIT:

So, if you have more than one `post` for a `postcategory`, update the model to:

```
var PostCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postid: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
  categoryid: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  createddate:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Comment: Good approach. Thanks. But i have more than one post. postcategories returns me list. And i must find all post to send them view.

Comment: I edited my answer. `postid` is now surrounded by `[]`. If you are satisfied, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is :

```
PostCategory.find({categoryid:category._id.str},function(err,postcategories){
    if(err) return next(err);

    var ids = [];
    _.each(postcategories, function(postCategory){
        ids.push(postCategory.postid);
    });

    Post.find({_id : { $in : ids } },function(err,posts){
        if(err) return next(err);

        return res.render(__dirname + "/views/categorydetail",  {
            title: 'İletişim',
            stylesheet: 'contact'
        });
    });
)};
```

In my example, i use underscoreJS to fetch postCategories List

Comment: It's not the best approach (neither the simplest way) using Mongoose. Check out the doc here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html